# Android code to Disconnect Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am a newbie to Android. I have created a Bluetooth module which turns Bluetooth ON/OFF (separate button), Scan nearby devices (used a separate button) and Show Paired Devices (separate button). Now if we click on scan, it will show a list of devices including a small pair button and connect button beside each listed device.

I wrote code for both pair and connect and working fine. Now I want to disconnect the connection by clicking the same connect button again.and the text inside the connect button should show "Disconnect" as soon as I connect to specified device. If I click on connect, it is connecting to the device but not disconnecting.

Here is the sample code:

```
package net.londatiga.android.bluetooth;

import java.util.List;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.drm.DrmStore.Action;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DeviceListAdapter extends  BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
    private List<BluetoothDevice> mData;
    private OnPairButtonClickListener mListener;
    private String str;
    Button btnSend;
    Connect con=null;
    Button connectbtn;
    //ProgressDialog mConnectingDlg;



    public DeviceListAdapter(Context context) { 
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);        
    }

    public void setData(List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public void setListener(OnPairButtonClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (mData == null) ? 0 : mData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }




    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {          
            convertView         =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_device, null);

            holder              = new ViewHolder();         
            holder.nameTv       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.addressTv    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            holder.pairBtn      = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pair);
            holder.connectbtn       = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

         final BluetoothDevice device   = mData.get(position);

        holder.nameTv.setText(device.getName());
        holder.addressTv.setText(device.getAddress());
        holder.pairBtn.setText((device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) ? "Unpair" : "Pair");
        holder.pairBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onPairButtonClick(position);
                }
            }
        });


          //  holder.connectbtn.setText((device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) ? "Disonnect" : "connect");
            holder.connectbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s=holder.connectbtn.getText().toString();

       Connect con=new Connect(new Connect.P25ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStartConnecting() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuccess() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(String error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
      con.connect(device);
   System.out.println("Device is connected");    



            }










            });




        return convertView;
}

    static class ViewHolder {
        Button connectbtn;
        TextView nameTv;
        TextView addressTv;
        Button pairBtn;
    }

    public interface OnPairButtonClickListener {
        public abstract void onPairButtonClick(int position);
    }




    }
```

Comment: I advice you to take a look at this project https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt
It's based on Google-Sample project about how to use ble on an Android application.